How do I extract a monthly summary of CREDIT & DEBT amounts from my bank statement in Google Sheets?
Suppose I have the following type of data in google sheets (Date format is English DD/MM/YYYY)
It reflects a typical bank statement going back 10 years (so thousands of such debit/credit entries)
| A            | B        | C      | D



Date
Debit
Credit
Closing Balance




16-12-2023
0
50
100


24-12-2023
20
0
80


27-12-2023
0
10
90


29-12-2023
15
0
75


01-01-2024
0
30
105


12-01-2024
5
0
100


24-01-2024
0
10
110



I want to be able to scan the data row (A) and extract monthly summery of how much debit and credit is being used. So ultimately I want to have a create a new series of tables which have the following report. It should add all up.



Date
Debit
Credit




Dec-2023
35
60


Jan-2024
5
40



How would I go about doing this?
I have tried using sumif() but how do I deal with the conditional debit and credit columns?


You may try:
=query({index(if(len(A2:A),eomonth(A2:A,),)),B2:C},"select Col1,sum(Col2),sum(Col3) Where Col1 is not null group by Col1
        label Col1 'Date',sum(Col2) 'Debit',sum(Col3) 'Credit' format Col1 'mmm-YYY' ")



thank you! I did find another method just as soon as i finished typing the question but yours is more elegant!
